# Markers and words not aligned in Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, seaborn, legend

For some reason I am not able to get a perfectly alignment between the markers and the words in the legend box .

[image: 1]

If you look the words, they are not aligned with the center of the bluish dots. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=300)
sns.set_style("ticks")

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.scatterplot(x="d47", y="D47 (raw)", linewidth=0, palette="Paired", hue=eth1_2.Sample.tolist(), data=eth1_2, legend="brief")
sns.lineplot(x='d47', y=reg47, data=eth1_2, label="y = " + str(round(slope47,5)) + "x + " + str(round(interc47,5)))
plt.ylim(-0.8, -0.3)
plt.ylabel("$\Delta_{47}$", size=14)
plt.xlim(-15, 25)
plt.xlabel("$\delta^{47}$", size=14)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False, fontsize=8, labelspacing=0.5)

plt.savefig("Pluto Monitoring.jpg", bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dont `round` those values

Comment: It does not solve the problem.

Comment: For the legend, the default y-offset assumes lowercase text.  As your texts are uppercase, you might try `plt.legend(..., scatteryoffsets=0.5)` or similar (the values for y-offset go from 0 at the bottom to 1 at the top. More info: [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Comment: Fantastic, I managed to get a way better alignment. Many thanks for the help!